# How to get some field from json object through xhr response

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, xmlhttprequest

my json object look like this 
{"status":"4",
 "detail_user":{
    "userId" : "1",
    "fullName" : Diga
    }
}

and my XmlHttpRequest

```
var email    = $$(page.container).find('input[name="email"]').val();
var password = $$(page.container).find('input[name="password"]').val();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){ 
  //var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  //alert(response.status);
  //alert(response.detail_user);
  var data=xhr.response;
  var data2=xhr.responseText; // respon like json object above
  alert(data);
  alert(data2);
  alert(data2.detail_user);
  alert(getJSON(data2.status)); //respon undefined
  var asd = JSON.stringify(data2).replace(/\"/g,"");
  alert(asd);
  console.log(xhr.response);//this is the response from the server
  }
}
params = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
xhr.open("POST", server+"sign-in/auth",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.send(params);
```

my coding in cordova and phonegap, actually for show all object of json success but when i show only some field i get respon undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data2` was a string, hence doesn't have property `status`. Change:

```
alert(getJSON(data2.status));
```

to

```
alert(getJSON(data2).status);
```

I assumed function `getJSON()` is returning JS object.

Comment: i already implement your suggest but still not work for me still get alert undefined , actually i have been try in use Json.parse but not working that make me confuse all data can be show but when i want to show some field it's not work

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(data, (key, value) => {
```

console.log(key); // log the current property name, the last is "".
  return value;     // return the unchanged property value.
});